# how to make a setup of c#.net project with relative image path

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, deployment, relative-path

I am using avatar photos in my application , in my app I created an Image folder in which I kept those pics. And as a path used relative ie;

```
images\gravatar.png
```

Also , made *Copy to Output Directory - Copy to*

But when I am making a setup and installing it on client machines its not able to find the path and give Unhandled Exception error on the path.
I tried researching only thing I got was how to use in development not in Deployment.

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you have the correct permissions to write it (you should, since it's installing, but just ensuring) ? You could also put a try/catch block around that area, and try to log some more info, and post back ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a relative path, set a constant for where the executable started from. Then the paths can be relative to that one.

```
public static readonly string APPLICATION_ROOT_PATH = Application.StartupPath + "\\";
public static readonly string IMAGES_PATH = APPLICATION_ROOT_PATH + "\\images";
```

Now you can use those constants like any other path. For example:

```
m_openFileDlg.InitialDirectory = className.IMAGES_PATH;
```

Comment: In C# (like its predecessors), a backslash starts an escape sequence. "\n" is new line, "\t" is tab, etc. You can find a list of possible escape sequences [on the MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx). So if you want to actually have a backslash in your string, you need to escape it by adding a backslash before.